# Interacting with JFrame components

Tags: java, swing, gridview, jframe, components

I'm trying to build a very simple connect 4 game using Swing.
The main game works as intended, but when I use it as a component in a larger GUI, I can no longer interact with it.

This is the main GUI code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainLayout extends JFrame {

    public MainLayout(){

        // TOP PANEL, series of button using FlowLayout
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 30, 10));
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JButton newGameBtn = new JButton("New Game");
        topPanel.add(newGameBtn);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.cyan);
        this.setTitle("Connect 4");

        JPanel grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,7,3,3));
        grid.setBackground(Color.blue);

        board comp = new board(new Dimension(7,6), new Dimension(60, 60));
        comp.setFocusable(true);
        comp.setEnabled(true);
        this.getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setSize(420,430);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MainLayout mainWindow = new MainLayout();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The board component uses keyboard input to move a square around.

Comment: *"The board component uses keyboard input to move a square around"* - let me "guess", you're using a KeyListener

Comment: Yes, and the keyListener works fine for the board on its own but when I try to use it as a component in the grid layout it stops working.

Comment: That is because KeyEvents are only dispatched to the component with focus. When you have other components on the frame your component loses focus so it never receives the KeyEvent. Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should use `Key Bindings`. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and examples comparing KeyListener and Key Bindings.